# Display svg file in HTML

Tags: html, svg

I have this code:

```html
<img src="https://piuksu.github.io/svg.svg" width="100">
```

It does not work.
What do I have to do?

Comment: set the [SVG namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) properly.

Comment: The SVG file itself needs to be fixed as guided by Robert above and the answer below. .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An SVG image (like your `https://piuksu.github.io/svg.svg`) is an XML document. XML is a general markup language that can be used for a number of different purposes. The browser that is going to display the SVG image need to know what kind of XML document it is going to display. Therefor your must set the namespace (the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` attribute on `<svg>`) of the SVG image (and preferably also the XML declaration (the first line)).

So, the content of `https://piuksu.github.io/svg.svg` must be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100">
  <path d="M0 50 L25 50 L25 97 L75 97 L75 50 L97 50" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Inline example (there the URL is replaced by a data URI, but it works the same):

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNMCA1MCBMMjUgNTAgTDI1IDk3IEw3NSA5NyBMNzUgNTAgTDk3IDUwIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjMiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiLz4KPC9zdmc+" width="100"/>
```

Comment: While this is correct, it would be more helpful to the OP if you clarify that the given SVG file itself is badly syntaxed and requires the tweaks you outline.

Comment: @Martin good point. Now I think that we have a proper explanation.